# Searching Active Directory for "Office"

Tags: search, active-directory

Our AD is a bit of a mess and I'm trying to tidy things up a little bit. I'm trying to search AD to find anything in the 'Office' field. For example if 'Head Office' is in that box I need to find users who have this entered. See the image below.

[image: ADUC Group]

I've tried custom searches but the closest I've found is 'Office Location' which returns nothing. Google is less than helpful on this occasion.

Any tips welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most fields in active directory aren't really used for anything but custom-development.  You can do [custom-searches against Active Directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx)... but they're far-less than pretty.  The "Office" field you're talking about is called the "physicalDeliveryOfficeName" in Microsoft's LDAP lookups... so you'd build a query like:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(physicalDeliveryOfficeName=Head Office))
```

More information about the search syntax can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You can also find more attributes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675090(v=vs.85).aspx